# Making an Array that can hold data from a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a for loop that can get data at a .txt file (bday.readWord()). However I can't figure up how to call it up a for loop value so I can get the different values for DayCount. I need the five differnt values of DayCount so I can sort it, and be able to calculate the shortest date away.

```
for(int diffinday = 0; diffinday < myStrings.length; diffinday++) {
    // making another copy 
    bmonth = Integer.parseInt(myStrings[0]);
    bday = Integer.parseInt(myStrings[1]);
    byear = Integer.parseInt(myStrings[2]);
    LocalDate start = new LocalDate(year, month, day);
    LocalDate end = new LocalDate(year, bmonth, bday);
    int dayCount = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
    System.out.println(dayCount);

    // making an int array;
    // we can do 2 things make an if statement that
    // will identify or make an array that will store
    // the differneces in the dates!

    // we make an array that will sort out the dates

    // bad code incoming!
    // what if it were 100 lines hmmm?
    int [] myArray = new int [] { dayCount, dayCount, dayCount, dayCount, dayCount };
    myArray[diffinday] = dayCount;
    Arrays.sort(myArray);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));

    if(dayCount < 0) {
        System.out.println("This value is null!");              
    } else {
        // for now, we can only identify pos ints.
        // we need to make an array that will find
        // the closest date, W/O IT BEING NEGATIVE
        System.out.println("The closest birthday is " + myStrings[4]);
    }
```

The dayCount is supposed to be `[-238, -196, -103, -76, 96]` b/c from a seperate **.txt** file, the program is supposed to be calculating the difference between the dates. The output of this program since the `myStrings.length` is 5 is

```
[-238,-238,-238,-238,-238]
[-196,-196,-196,-196,-196]
... so on and so forth
```

It would be great if you could also help me sort out DayCount once your able to call up the correct for loop values, W/O it being negative. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question and your code do not match up.

Comment: How so? When I calculated the date (i didn't show the code for that), I used a for loop so it calculate it five different times (b/c they're 5 diff dates). However, I don't know how to store those 5 numbers. That's the question. How can I save those 5 numbers [-238, -196, etc, etc], and sort them out.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up the array like so:

```
int[] myArray = new int[5];
```

Which says to Java, "I want a new integer array which can store 5 items".

Thus, you could then make an array of any size that you want:

```
int x = 7;
int[] myArray = new int[x]
```

The values will be set to `null` initially, and then you can use your `for` loop to set them appropriately.

---

You could also use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which can have items added and removed from it dynamically.

For example, if I were using a simple `Scanner` and `ArrayList`, I could do the following:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Make the ArrayList

while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    myArrayList.add(scanner.nextInt()); //Add an item to the ArrayList
}

for (Integer i:myArrayList) { //Loop through all items in the ArrayList
    System.out.println(i);
}
```